# How to auto launch Apple Watch app when companion iOS app is running?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I believe it's RTFM kind of question, but I can't find the answer. I've created Apple Watch app which works just fine, gets paired with its companion iOS app, receives push notifications sent to main app, but it does not start when iOS app gets launched. Am I missing something? Should I run a background task just to check if main iOS app is alive?

Comment: My guess it's possible for Audio apps only?